# How do I access values of Ansible Facts when using a loop?

Tags: ansible

This works when I don't use a loop:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Get a cert from gRPC port
      get_certificate:
        host: "labrouter.abc.com"
        port: 50051
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: cert
    - name: Get Cert Data
      debug:
        msg: "Not_After: {{ cert.not_after }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Get Cert Data] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Not After: 20221210143235Z"
}
```

However, when I try to loop through my hosts like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Get a cert from gRPC port
      get_certificate:
        host: "{{ item }}"
        port: 50051
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: cert
      loop: "{{ groups['lab'] }}"
    - name: Get Cert Data
      debug:
        msg: "Not After: {{ cert.not_after }}"
```

I get this error:

```
The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'not_after'
```

My inventory file contains a single group called "lab" with one device "labrouter.abc.com" associated to it.

I want to be able to add more devices to the "lab" group and run this playbook so I can get the "not_after" value for each device. I can't figure out how to access the "not_after" value for each item in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop looping, and have Ansible do its implicit looping over the hosts:

```
---
- hosts: lab
  tasks:
    - name: Get a cert from gRPC port
      get_certificate:
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        port: 50051
      delegate_to: localhost
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: cert

    - name: Get Cert Data
      debug:
        msg: "Not After: {{ cert.not_after }}"
```

(As a general "best practices" thing, if you are looping over hosts, there's probably a better way to do it by setting the `hosts` value for the play to those hosts, and letting Ansible do its implicit looping.)

Comment: I tried that initially, but Ansible wants to ssh into the device (router) to establish connectivity and this is not allowed at the moment.

Comment: Add `gather_facts: no` to the play.

Comment: Tried doing this, but Ansible still tries to ssh to router.
---
- hosts: lab
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Get a cert from an gRPC port
      get_certificate:
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        port: 50051
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: cert
    - name: Get Cert Data
      debug:
        msg: "Not After: {{ cert.not_after }}"

Had to remove "delegate_to" so Ansible wouldn't try to connect to localhost.

Comment: You can put `connection: local` on the play and get rid of the `delegate_to: localhost`.  Also get rid of the `run_once: true`.

Comment: Your recommendations did help me loop through the hosts, however, I'm seeing some bad output. I'm assuming it probably has something to do with the module itself. For example, when I put a reachable and unreachable host in my host file, I get good outputs from both hosts. However, if I only leave the unreachable host in the host file then I get an error indicating the host was unreachable.

Comment: I'd have to see the output, but "unreachable" typically means ssh error.

Comment: Ok never mind, I see my mistake. I didn't remove run_once. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop):

> When you use `register` with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a `results` attribute that is a list of all responses from the module. This differs from the data structure returned when using `register` without a loop

The easiest way to fix your actual problem is to loop over the `results`:

```yaml
    - name: Get Cert Data
      debug:
        msg: "Not After: {{ item.not_after }}"
      loop: "{{ cert.results }}"
```

Although this is a direct answer to your question, if the final goal is to take actions on each target in the `lab` group, see [@Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372840/9401096) and drop your loop.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator, that did give me the answer I was looking for. Is it possible to not print the entire "results" list, and just print the debug msg?

Comment: Yes: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label